# How to fill in an online form and get results back in R

Tags: xml, r, forms, web-scraping, rselenium

Has anyone ever filled in a web form remotely from R?

I'd like to do some archery statistics in R using my scores. There is a very handy webpage, that gives you the classification and handicaps http://www.archersmate.co.uk/, which I naturally would want to include in my stats sheet.

Is it possible to fill this form in remotely and to get the results back to R???

Otherwise I would have to get all handicap tables and stick them into a database myself.

**UPDATE:
We've narrowed the problem down to the fact, that the form submit button is written in javascript.**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[r]+webscraping

Comment: @AriB.Friedman that's really not enough..  :)  this question involves understanding the [hcalc.js](http://www.archersmate.co.uk/scripts/ajax_hcalc.js) javascript, parsing through the `ajaxCalc()` and `ajaxiCalc()` functions to construct the `url` string used in the `/functions/iclass.php` call.  i don't see an example of all that using R on S.O.

Comment: @AnthonyDamico I suspected it wouldn't be.  But it gives her a starting point and a vocabulary, and thus a hope of narrowing her question.  You've nobly and ably done a lot of the work of narrowing the question, so perhaps you could edit the question to be more targeted?

Comment: The answers to this question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5396461/how-to-automate-multiple-requests-to-a-web-search-form-using-r) should help, as they are focused on automating the process of filling in a web form and bringing the results into R.

Comment: Yes, I knew it was not just web-scraping. Thanks @eipi10 that does look very promising.

Comment: @AnthonyDamico is right, the problem is hitting the submit button, as this part is written in javascript.

Comment: @eipi10  i don't think the difficult part is hitting enter, i think it's building the input and sending those to `iclass.php`?

Comment: Perhaps I'll need to do it in PHP or javascript and only grab the output back into R. I'll give it a hard stare!

Comment: @AnthonyDamico or you can inspect the network debug pane to reverse engineer the requests being sent to the server

Answer (score 9):

You can use the `RSelenium` package to fill out and submit web forms and to retrieve the results.

The following code leveraging [RSelenium](https://github.com/ropensci/RSelenium) will download data for an example input (Male, Under 18, Longbow, Bristol V, 500):

```
library(RSelenium)

# Start Selenium Server --------------------------------------------------------

checkForServer()
startServer()
remDrv <- remoteDriver()
remDrv$open()


# Simulate browser session and fill out form -----------------------------------

remDrv$navigate('http://www.archersmate.co.uk/')
remDrv$findElement(using = "xpath", "//input[@value = 'Male']")$clickElement()
Sys.sleep(2) 
remDrv$findElement(using = "xpath", "//select[@id = 'drpAge']/option[@value = 'Under 18']")$clickElement()
remDrv$findElement(using = "xpath", "//input[@value ='Longbow']")$clickElement() 
remDrv$findElement(using = "xpath", "//select[@id = 'rnd']/option[@value = 'Bristol V']")$clickElement()
remDrv$findElement(using = "xpath", "//input[@id ='scr']")$sendKeysToElement(list('5', '0', '0'))
remDrv$findElement(using = "xpath", "//input[@id = 'cmdCalc']")$clickElement()

# Retrieve and download results injecting javascript ---------------------------

Sys.sleep(2)
clsf <- remDrv$executeScript(script = 'return $("#txtClass").val();', args = list())[[1]]
hndcp <- remDrv$executeScript(script = 'return $("#txtHandicap").val();', args = list())[[1]]

remDrv$quit()
remDrv$closeServer()
```

The default browser for `RSelenium` is Firefox. However, `RSelenium` even supports headless browsing using `PhantomJS`. For leveraging `PhanomJS` you just need to

- [download PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/download.html) and place it in the users path
- replace the code snippets at the beginning and at the end like described next

Default browsing (like shown above):

```
checkForServer()
startServer()
remDrv <- remoteDriver()

...

remDrv$quit()
remDrv$closeServer()
```

Headless browsing:

```
pJS <- phantom()
remDrv <- remoteDriver(browserName = 'phantomjs')

...

remDrv$close()
pJS$stop()
```

Comment: From the source code how did you know to chose: using = "xpath", "//input[@value = 'Male']"?? How would I know how to fill in text on this webpage: https://ois.dk/

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at Rcurl's `postForm` [here](http://svitsrv25.epfl.ch/R-doc/library/RCurl/html/postForm.html) and theres also a nice tutorial [here](http://rfunction.com/archives/1816)

Comment: I don't think RCurl can solve it, as it is not a conventional HTML form.

Answer (score 0):

this might not help you, as I am searching for an answer to a similar problem, but looking at the URL you would like to scrape, the forms to fill are actuall HTML Forms, and you can get the description by:

```
url <- "http://www.archersmate.co.uk/"
forms <- getHTMLFormDescription(url)
```

Also look at the package "RHTMLForms" on omegahat.org

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be done in RCurl because the form triggers an ajax event, so the postForm function will not be enough.