# What if I want to web scrape with R for a page with parameters?

Tags: r, web-scraping

The page I would like to scrape here: http://stoptb.org/countries/tbteam/searchExperts.asp requires the submission of parameters in this page: http://stoptb.org/countries/tbteam/experts.asp in order to get the data out. Since the parameters are not nested in the URL, I don't know how to pass them with R. Is there a way to do this in R?

(BTW, I know next to nothing about ASP, so maybe that's the component I'm missing.)

Comment: +1. This sounds like a problem for perl, but if it can be done in R, I'd like to see it.

Comment: Take a look at the `RCurl` package.

Comment: Thanks, Thomas. Can you suggest a specific function in RCurl, maybe with an example of passing a parameter to the web site?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `RHTMLForms`

You may need to install it first:

```
# install.packages("RHTMLForms", repos = "http://www.omegahat.org/R")
```

or under windows you may need

```
# install.packages("RHTMLForms", repos = "http://www.omegahat.org/R", type = "source")


 require(RHTMLForms)
 require(RCurl)
 require(XML)
 forms = getHTMLFormDescription("http://stoptb.org/countries/tbteam/experts.asp")
 fun = createFunction(forms$sExperts)
 # find experts with expertise in "Infection control: Engineering Consultant"
 results <- fun(Expertise = "Infection control: Engineering Consultant")

 tableData <- getNodeSet(htmlParse(results), "//*/table[@class = 'data']")
 readHTMLTable(tableData[[1]])

#                              V1                   V2                     V3
#1                                                <NA>                   <NA>
#2                 Name of Expert Country of Residence                  Email
#3               Girmay, Desalegn             Ethiopia    deskebede@yahoo.com
#4            IVANCHENKO, VARVARA              Estonia v.ivanchenko81@mail.ru
#5                   JAUCOT, Alex              Belgium  alex.jaucot@gmail.com
#6 Mulder, Hans Johannes Henricus              Namibia        hmulder@iway.na
#7                    Walls, Neil            Australia        neil@nwalls.com
#8                 Zuccotti, Thea                Italy     thea_zuc@yahoo.com
#                  V4
#1               <NA>
#2 Number of Missions
#3                  0
#4                  3
#5                  0
#6                  0
#7                  0
#8                  1
```

or create a reader to return a table

```
 returnTable <- function(results){
  tableData <- getNodeSet(htmlParse(results), "//*/table[@class = 'data']")
  readHTMLTable(tableData[[1]])
 }
 fun = createFunction(forms$sExperts, reader = returnTable)
 fun(CBased = "Bhutan") # find experts based in Bhutan
#                 V1                   V2                      V3
#1                                   <NA>                    <NA>
#2    Name of Expert Country of Residence                   Email
#3 Wangchuk, Lungten               Bhutan drlungten@health.gov.bt
#                  V4
#1               <NA>
#2 Number of Missions
#3                  2
```

Comment: This looks excellent. I couldn't make the download work ```package ‘RHTMLForms’ is not available (for R version 2.15.3)``` Do I need to upgrade to the latest version of R?

Comment: Are you using windows or linux. Call setRepositories() and make certain Omegahat is selected.

Comment: If you are using windows you may need to then call `install.packages("RHTMLForms", type = "source")`

Comment: Ah jeez sorry I missed this already in the commented out portion.

Answer (score 2):

Sending a form to a web server normally is done via what is called an HTTP POST request (getting an ordinary web page is an HTTP GET request).

The POST request spec lets you bundle up all the parameters into part of the HTTP headers.

`RCurl` can do this, or you might try the `httr` package which has a `POST` function that takes an R list of parameters to pass on with the POST request.

Another tip: use Firebug or other browser debugger to inspect what a page has sent as parameters to POST requests.

Comment: Okay this is making sense, thank you. That tip makes sense as the missing bit for me.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to prepare a full working example for 
    "http://hp2010.nhlbihin.net/atpiii/calculator.asp?usertype=prof".

```
 #Example the data required.
 medication <- 0; #c("0", "1")
 sex <- "male";   #c("female", "male")
 smoker <- 1;     # c("0", "1")
 age <- 20;       #
 cholesterol<-130;#
 hdl <- 20;       #
 systolic <- 130; #

 #thanks to http://www.omegahat.org/RHTMLForms/
  download.file("http://www.omegahat.org/RHTMLForms/RHTMLForms_0.6-0.tar", tempdir())
  install.packages(file.path(paste(tempdir(),"RHTMLForms_0.6-0.tar",  'RHTMLForms_0.6-0.tar')),repos=NULL, type='source')

#----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 #libraries
 library(RHTMLForms)
 library(xlsx)
 library(XML)
 library(RCurl)

 # http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5396461/how-to-automate-multiple-requests-to-a-web-search-form-using-r
 setwd("C:\\MyPath")
 data<-read.csv("MyData.csv")
 # get form description
 url<-"http://hp2010.nhlbihin.net/atpiii/calculator.asp?usertype=prof"
 forms <- getHTMLFormDescription(url);

 # create a function using form description, to query the url
 efun  <- createFunction(forms[[1]]);


 result<-matrix(NA,nrow=dim(data)[1],ncol=9,dimnames=list(1:dim(data)[1],c("IDNO","medication","sex","smoker","age","cholesterol","hdl","systolic","risk_persent")))

# If you had an actual file you could use this for loop, for now you can use the example data
#  for(i in 1: dim(data)[1]){
#    medication <- 0;#c("0", "1")
#    sex <- ifelse(data$gender1[i]==0,"female","male") ;#c("female", "male")
#    smoker <- ifelse(data$cig1c[i]<2,0,1);# c("0", "1")
#    age <- data$age1c[i];#
#    cholesterol <- data$chol1[i];#
#    hdl <- data$hdl1[i];#
#    systolic <- round(data$sbp1c[i]);#

    if(age<20||age>99||systolic>200||systolic<90||cholesterol<130||cholesterol>320||hdl<20||hdl>100||is.na(sex)||is.na(smoker)||is.na(age)||is.na(cholesterol)||is.na(hdl)||is.na(systolic)){    
    result[i,]<-c(data$IDNO[i],medication,sex,smoker,age,cholesterol,hdl,systolic,NA)
    next;
  }

  # extract webpage by passing required arguments to function
  page  <- efun(medication = toString(medication), sex = toString(sex), smoker = toString(smoker), age = toString(age), cholesterol = toString(cholesterol), hdl = toString(hdl), systolic = toString(systolic));
  #pause the algorithm, so that you do not request too often from the server
  Sys.sleep(.1)
  # parse webpage and return html tree
  doc   <- htmlTreeParse(page, asText = T, useInternalNodes = T);
  # extract table from the html tree
  tab   <- readHTMLTable(doc);
  result[i,]<-c(data$IDNO[i],medication,sex,smoker,age,cholesterol,hdl,systolic,as.numeric(gsub('[%a-zA-Z ]','',(tab[[1]][11,2]))))
 #system.time
 # }#end of for loop

 write.csv(result,file="MyResults.csv")
```