# Scraping table from ASP.NET webpage with JavaScript buttons using R

Tags: javascript, asp.net, r, http, rcurl

I've poured over related questions to no avail. I need to scrape a table of price information from an ASP.NET webpage (http://www.spp.org/LIP.asp) based on dates and hours that I specify. I am comfortable with and want to use R. My basic stumbling block is that the URL doesn't reflect search parameters, it's static, and I also don't know how to submit an HTML form with Javascript in it on an ASP.NET site.

I viewed the source code for the URL above. I found that within an iframe is a link to another page for 'source data': http://www.spp.org/LIPPosting/LIP.aspx. I tried doing a POST request in R based on this StackOverflow thread: [What if I want to web scrape with R for a page with parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16601520/what-if-i-want-to-web-scrape-with-r-for-a-page-with-parameters).

```
##ASP.NET site scrape
forms = getHTMLFormDescription("http://www.spp.org/LIPPosting/LIP.aspx")
# Name the list for easy reference
names(forms)='spp'
# Use the createFunction tool so I can submit a search
fun = createFunction(forms$spp, verbose=T)
# Submit an HTML form looking for data using all form defaults
# Except change the hour to '03'
results <- fun(ddlHour = '03')
# Grab the table results from the HTML based on its id tag  
tableData <- getNodeSet(htmlParse(results), "//*/table[@id = 'dgLIP']")
readHTMLTable(tableData[[1]])
```

The HTML results show that in the 'hour' form element I did select '03'.

```
           <td style="height: 42px; width: 77px;">
<span id="lblLIPHour">Hour</span><br><select name="ddlHour" id="ddlHour"><option value="1">01</option>
<option value="2">02</option>
<option selected value="3">03</option>
<option value="4">04</option>
<option value="5">05</option>
<option value="6">06</option>
<option value="7">07</option>
<option value="8">08</option>
```

However, this request does not get passed to the server, because when I look at the actual table results it is for the current time, not '03'.

```
> readHTMLTable(tableData[[1]])
   Publish Date   Price Date                PNode Price        Parent PNode Settlement Location
1  201402281552 201402281600                 AECI 23.45                AECI                AECI
2  201402281552 201402281600                 AMRN 23.45                AMRN                AMRN
3  201402281552 201402281600                 BLKW 23.45                BLKW                BLKW
4  201402281552 201402281600                 CLEC 23.45                CLEC                CLEC
5  201402281552 201402281600         CSWS_AECC_LA 23.45        CSWS_AECC_LA           AECC_CSWS
```

In addition, I can only get the HTML for the page that gets returned from the server, which does not contain all of the results. In reality, there are JavaScript arrow buttons on the bottom of that page that allow me to tab between all the results when I am in the webpage.

In the webpage itself, to see results after choosing from a dropdown menu, I have to hit the 'view' button. Is there a way to replicate this in R to get my '03' parameters sent as a query to the server to return new HTML to the webpage?

If I can do that, I can write something to "push" the page arrows as well.

Comment: I hope others will give you more reason for optimism, but my advice is don't do it. Use python with the selenium driver, it will be much easier even if you don't know python in advance. I say this as someone who loves R and tries to use it for everything, but in this case I don't think it's the right tool for the job.

Comment: Thanks Ista...I'd never heard of Selenium before getting into this little pickle. Do you think their is an advantage to using a Python driver over the R package suggested by jdharrison below?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Selenium for this. See http://johndharrison.github.io/RSelenium/ . DISCLAIMER I am the author of the RSelenium package. A basic vignette on operation can be viewed at [RSelenium basics](http://rpubs.com/johndharrison/12843) and 
[RSelenium: Testing Shiny apps](http://rpubs.com/johndharrison/13408)

```
require(RSelenium)
# RSelenium::startServer() # if needed
remDr <- remoteDriver()
remDr$open()
remDr$setImplicitWaitTimeout(3000)
remDr$navigate("http://www.spp.org/LIP.asp")
remDr$switchToFrame("content_frame")
dateElem <- remDr$findElement(using = "id", "txtLIPDate") # select the date
dateRequired <- "01/14/2014"
dateElem$clearElement()
dateElem$sendKeysToElement(list("01/14/2014", key = "enter")) # send a date to app
hourElem <- remDr$findElement(using = "css selector", '#ddlHour [value="5"]') # select the 5th hour
hourElem$clickElement() # select this hour
buttonElem <-remDr$findElement(using = "id", "cmdView")
buttonElem$clickElement() # click the view button

#Sys.sleep(5)
tableElem <- remDr$findElement(using = "id", "dgLIP")
readHTMLTable(htmlParse(tableElem$getElementAttribute("outerHTML")[[1]]))

[1] "tableElem$getElementAttribute(\"outerHTML\")"
$dgLIP
V1           V2                   V3    V4                  V5                  V6
1  Publish Date   Price Date                PNode Price        Parent PNode Settlement Location
2  201401132252 201401132300                 AECI 19.14                AECI                AECI
3  201401132252 201401132300                 AMRN 18.87                AMRN                AMRN
4  201401132252 201401132300                 BLKW 20.28                BLKW                BLKW
5  201401132252 201401132300                 CLEC 18.99                CLEC                CLEC
6  201401132252 201401132300         CSWS_AECC_LA 19.77        CSWS_AECC_LA           AECC_CSWS
7  201401132252 201401132300  CSWS_GREEN_LIGHT_LA  18.5 CSWS_GREEN_LIGHT_LA        GSEC_GL_CSWS
8  201401132252 201401132300              CSWS_LA 19.01             CSWS_LA           AEPM_CSWS
9  201401132252 201401132300              CSWS_LA 19.01             CSWS_LA            AEP_LOSS
10 201401132252 201401132300         CSWS_OMPA_LA 18.66        CSWS_OMPA_LA           OMPA_CSWS
11 201401132252 201401132300      CSWS_TENASKA_LA 18.95     CSWS_TENASKA_LA        GATEWAY_LOAD
12 201401132252 201401132300      CSWS112_WGORLD1  18.7             CSWS_LA           AEPM_CSWS
13 201401132252 201401132300      CSWS112_WGORLD1  18.7             CSWS_LA            AEP_LOSS
14 201401132252 201401132300      CSWS116PEORILD1  18.9             CSWS_LA           AEPM_CSWS
15 201401132252 201401132300      CSWS116PEORILD1  18.9             CSWS_LA            AEP_LOSS
16 201401132252 201401132300    CSWS121EASTLDXFL1 18.92             CSWS_LA           AEPM_CSWS
17 201401132252 201401132300    CSWS121EASTLDXFL1 18.92             CSWS_LA            AEP_LOSS
18 201401132252 201401132300      CSWS121LYNN4LD1 18.91             CSWS_LA           AEPM_CSWS
19 201401132252 201401132300      CSWS121LYNN4LD1 18.91             CSWS_LA            AEP_LOSS
20 201401132252 201401132300   CSWS12TH_STLD69_12 18.92             CSWS_LA           AEPM_CSWS
21 201401132252 201401132300   CSWS12TH_STLD69_12 18.92             CSWS_LA            AEP_LOSS
22 201401132252 201401132300 CSWS12TH_STLD69_12_2 18.92             CSWS_LA           AEPM_CSWS
23 201401132252 201401132300 CSWS12TH_STLD69_12_2 18.92             CSWS_LA            AEP_LOSS
24 201401132252 201401132300      CSWS136_YALELD1  18.9             CSWS_LA           AEPM_CSWS
25 201401132252 201401132300      CSWS136_YALELD1  18.9             CSWS_LA            AEP_LOSS
26 201401132252 201401132300  CSWS141_PINELDXFMR1 19.09             CSWS_LA           AEPM_CSWS
27          < >         <NA>                 <NA>  <NA>                <NA>                <NA>
```

Comment: Ok I'm intrigued! I'm going to give it a whirl Monday

Comment: I am stuck at 'remDr$open()' getting the error 'Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : couldn't connect to host'. I installed in R using the devtools package and downloading from GitHub.

Comment: @sclarky you need to have a selenium server running Refer to the RSelenium basics vignette.

Comment: I'm sorry @jdharrison this is a foreign language to me. I ran both the checkserver and startserver functions, and when I navigate to the bin folder in the RSelenium package the selenium jar file is there. However I still get the error

Comment: It maybe an issue with java. Do you have Java or Java + JDK installed on that system? You can check as follows 1. Go go to command prompt
2. type "java -version"

Comment: weird I do when I search in my programs, but in the command prompt it says 'java' is not recognized as an internal or external command, etc.

Comment: If you are running windows you can add the directory the java binary is in to your path and hopefully that would sort out the problem. some info here http://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.xml

Comment: that was my bad -- I had corrupted the jar file by interrupting its download before. Thanks for your patience @jdharrison

Answer (score 0):

For posterity I wanted to also put up the code I am using for the page click between results pages (there is no 'Show All' option). I have RSelenium clicking through all pages until there is no longer a 'forward click' option. On each page it scrapes the HTML table into a list:

```
# Get the first page of results
tableElem <- remDr$findElement(using = "id", "dgLIP")
tmp <- readHTMLTable(htmlParse(tableElem$getElementAttribute("outerHTML")[[1]]))
hourlyData <- list()
# Save the first table without the last row, which is gibberish
hourlyData[[1]] <- tmp[[1]][-27,]

# Click the 'greater than' arrow javascript href element to get to next page  
acc <- 2
while("javascript:__doPostBack('dgLIP$_ctl29$_ctl1','')" %in% unlist(lapply(remDr$findElements("css selector", "[href]"), function(x){x$getElementAttribute("href")}))) {
  webElems <- remDr$findElements("css selector", "[href]")
  clickers <- unlist(lapply(webElems, function(x){x$getElementAttribute("href")}))
  pager <- webElems[[which(clickers == "javascript:__doPostBack('dgLIP$_ctl29$_ctl1','')")]]
  pager$clickElement()
  tableElem <- remDr$findElement(using = "id", "dgLIP")
  tmp <- readHTMLTable(htmlParse(tableElem$getElementAttribute("outerHTML")[[1]]))
  hourlyData[[acc]] <- tmp[[1]]
  acc <- acc + 1
  Sys.sleep(3)
}
```