# R - web scraping dynamic form with inputs

Tags: html, asp.net, r, dynamic, web-scraping

I'm trying to achieve the following task in R.
This website provides sub-district level statistics (in tables) on agricultural data in India: http://agcensus.dacnet.nic.in/tehsilsummarytype.aspx
My understanding is that this is called a dynamic form as the options change depending on the entries made. Specifically I would like to download tables for:

1. State = Andhra Pradesh
2. District = Adilabad, Anantapur, Kadapa, ... (8 total)
3. Tahsil = Mancherial, Kasipet (those are just 2 examples  for District = Adilabad; total 158)

Then I want "Average Holdings by size" for all social groups, all genders and the Total.

Based on this post [What if I want to web scrape with R for a page with parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16601520/what-if-i-want-to-web-scrape-with-r-for-a-page-with-parameters) I think the way to go is to use getHTMLFormDescription(). However, since my form is dynamic, I can't follow the route that was suggested in the other post. The createFunction() line returns an error:
 "*Error in writeFunction(formDescription, character(), url, con, verbose = verbose,  :  You should provide a form description here. See getFormDescription()."

In the RHTMLForms package that can be downloaded from  the omegahat webpage,
there is this function that (as the name suggests) should do what I need:

```
function function(desc, omit = character(), drop = TRUE, ..., verbose = FALSE) {
# Discard the elements that we are omitting.
 if(length(omit)) {
   idx = match(omit, names(desc$elements), 0)
  k = class(desc$elements)
 desc$elements <- desc$elements[-idx]
class(desc$elements) = k }

 # If no more elements left as a result of omitting them, just return the description
 # as there are definitely no more dynamic components left.
if(length(desc$elements) == 0)
 return(desc)

   # Now find the dynamic components.
 dyn = sapply(desc$elements, inherits, "DynamicHTMLFormElement")
if(!any(dyn)) 
return(desc)

pivot = desc$elements[[min(which(dyn))]]

 # We will need to submit the form for each value of this dynamic element, so
  # get the URI.  If the URI changes depending on the value, we are out of     luck!!
url = mergeURI(URI(desc$formAttributes["action"]), URI(desc$url)) 

 # Prepare the return value with the pivot information and we will build up
 # the branches by looping over the possible values.
 descriptions = list(elementName = pivot$name,
                 description = pivot,
                 values = list())   

 omit = c(omit, pivot$name)

 for(i in names(pivot$options)) {
   # Create the arguments for the submission. We may need to include them all.
 args = list(i)
 names(args)[1] = pivot$name

 if(verbose) 
   cat("Checking ", pivot$name, " - option", i, "\n")

  #XX we may need to provide all the arguments rather than just this one.
  # or perhaps cumulate them for the elements we have already deal with.
  # We have the defaults and the possible values from the original description.
 page = formQuery(args, toString(url), desc, .checkArgs = FALSE, ...)
  # Make certain that we turn the checkDynamic off here to avoid recursively.
 tmp = getHTMLFormDescription(page, asText = TRUE, handlers = multiFormElementHandlers(url, checkDynamic = FALSE))
 tmp = getDynamicHTMLFormDescription(tmp, omit = omit)

   # Now remove the elements that we are omitting. This leaves a subset of the form.
 if(drop) {
    idx = match(omit, names(tmp$elements), 0)

    if(any(is.na(idx))) {
      k = class(tmp$elements)
      tmp$elements = tmp$elements[is.na(idx)]
      class(tmp$elements) = k
    }

    class(tmp) <- c("HTMLFormSubset", class(tmp))        
 }

 descriptions$values[[i]] = tmp
 }

class(descriptions) <- c("DynamicFormElementPath")

descriptions
}
```

However, I can't get this to work either - the call getDynamicHTMLFormDescription("http://agcensus.dacnet.nic.in/tehsilsummarytype.aspx") gives "Error in desc$elements : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors".

Does anybody have advise on how to go about this? Once I have a way to fill out the form and access the table for each sub-district (tahsil), I know how to get the data in shape. It's really only about making R fill out this (particular) form.

Any help is welcome!
Michael Kaiser
(Staff Research Associate, UCSD)

Comment: When selecting 'Andhra Pradesh' the 'District' drop-down menu shows 23 entries and not 8 as you mentioned above. Was this a typo or are you interested in 8 specific districts out of those 23?

Comment: Sorry about this - I should have been more specific. Yes, I'm interested in 8 specific of these 23 districts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a solution using `RSelenium` for downloading data for

1. State = Andhra Pradesh
2. District = Adilabadt
3. Tahsil = Mancherial
4. Tables = Average Size of Operational Holding by Size Group

The remaining fields use the default input parameters.

```
library(RSelenium)
library(XML)
library(magrittr)

# Start Selenium Server --------------------------------------------------------

checkForServer()
startServer()
remDrv <- remoteDriver()
remDrv$open()


# Simulate browser session and fill out form -----------------------------------

remDrv$navigate('http://agcensus.dacnet.nic.in/tehsilsummarytype.aspx')
remDrv$findElement(using = "xpath", 
                   "//select[@name = '_ctl0:ContentPlaceHolder1:DropDownList1']/option[@value = '1a']")$clickElement()
remDrv$findElement(using = "xpath",
                   "//select[@name = '_ctl0:ContentPlaceHolder1:DropDownList9']/option[@value = '19']")$clickElement()
remDrv$findElement(using = "xpath",
                   "//option[@value = '33']")$clickElement()
remDrv$findElement(using = "xpath",
                   "//select[@name = '_ctl0:ContentPlaceHolder1:DropDownList3']/option[@value = '4']")$clickElement()
# Click submit
remDrv$findElement(using = "xpath",
                   "//input[@value = 'Submit']")$clickElement()


# Retrieve and download results ------------------------------------------------

table <- remDrv$getPageSource()[[1]] %>% 
  htmlParse %>% 
  readHTMLTable %>% 
  extract2(4)

remDrv$quit()
remDrv$closeServer()

head(table)

#      V1                      V2                     V3
# 1 SI No. Size of Holding(in ha.) Institutional Holdings
# 2    (1)                     (2)                    (3)
# 3      1                MARGINAL                      0
# 4      2                   SMALL                      0
# 5      3              SEMIMEDIUM                      0
# 6      4                  MEDIUM                      0
```

However, the static solution above only answers parts of your questions, namely how to fill out the web form using R.

The tricky thing on your web page is that the values in the different drop-down menus depend on each other.

Below, you will find a solution which takes into account those dependencies without the need that you know the respective district and tehsils IDs upfront.

The code below downloads data for

1. State = GOA
2. Tables = Average Size of Operational Holding by Size Group

including all districts and all tehsils. I used GOA as the primary anchor but you can easily select another state of your choice.

```
library(RSelenium)
library(XML)
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)

# Start Selenium Server --------------------------------------------------------

checkForServer()
startServer()
remDrv <- remoteDriver()
remDrv$open()


# Simulate browser session and fill out form -----------------------------------

remDrv$navigate('http://agcensus.dacnet.nic.in/tehsilsummarytype.aspx')

# Select 27a == GOA as the anchor
remDrv$findElement(using = "xpath", 
                   "//select[@name = '_ctl0:ContentPlaceHolder1:DropDownList1']/option[@value = '27a']")$clickElement()
# Select 4 == Average Size of Operational Holding by Size Group 
remDrv$findElement(using = "xpath",
                   "//select[@name = '_ctl0:ContentPlaceHolder1:DropDownList3']/option[@value = '4']")$clickElement()

# Get all district IDs and the respective names belonging to GOA
district_IDs <- remDrv$findElements(using = "xpath",
                                "//select[@name = '_ctl0:ContentPlaceHolder1:DropDownList9']/option") %>%
  lapply(function(x){x$getElementAttribute('value')}) %>% 
  unlist

district_names <- remDrv$findElements(using = "xpath",
                                    "//select[@name = '_ctl0:ContentPlaceHolder1:DropDownList9']/option") %>%
  lapply(function(x){x$getElementText()}) %>% 
  unlist


# Retrieve and download results ------------------------------------------------

result <- data.frame(district = character(), teshil = character(), 
                     V1 = character(), V2 = character(), V3 = character())

for (i in seq_along(district_IDs)) {

  remDrv$findElement(using = "xpath",
                     paste0("//select[@name = '_ctl0:ContentPlaceHolder1:DropDownList9']/option[@value = ", 
                          "'", district_IDs[i], "']"))$clickElement()
  Sys.sleep(2)

  # Get all tehsil IDs and names from the currently selected district
  tehsil_IDs <- remDrv$findElements(using = "xpath",
                     "//div[@id = '_ctl0_ContentPlaceHolder1_Panel4']/select/option") %>%
    lapply(function(x){x$getElementAttribute('value')}) %>%
    unlist

  tehsil_names <- remDrv$findElements(using = "xpath",
                                                    "//div[@id = '_ctl0_ContentPlaceHolder1_Panel4']/select/option") %>%
    lapply(function(x){x$getElementText()}) %>%
    unlist

  for (j in seq_along(tehsil_IDs)) {

    remDrv$findElement(using = "xpath",
                        paste0("//div[@id = '_ctl0_ContentPlaceHolder1_Panel4']/select/option[@value = ",
                               "'", tehsil_IDs[j], "']"))$clickElement()
    Sys.sleep(2)

    # Click submit and download data of the selected tehsil
    remDrv$findElement(using = "xpath",
                       "//input[@value = 'Submit']")$clickElement()
    Sys.sleep(2)

    # Download data for current tehsil
    tehsil_data <- remDrv$getPageSource()[[1]] %>% 
      htmlParse %>% 
      readHTMLTable %>% 
      extract2(4) %>% 
      extract(c(-1, -2), )

    result <- data.frame(district = district_names[i], tehsil = tehsil_names[j],
                         tehsil_data) %>% rbind(result, .)

    remDrv$goBack()
    Sys.sleep(2)
  }   
}

remDrv$quit()
remDrv$closeServer()

result %<>% as_data_frame %>%
  rename(
    si_no = V1,
    holding_size = V2, 
    inst_holdings = V3
    ) %>% 
  mutate(
    si_no = as.numeric(as.character(si_no)),
    inst_holdings = as.numeric(as.character(inst_holdings))
    )

dim(result)
# [1] 66  5

head(result)
# district tehsil si_no   holding_size inst_holdings
# 1 NORTH GOA  ponda     1       MARGINAL          0.34
# 2 NORTH GOA  ponda     2          SMALL          0.00
# 3 NORTH GOA  ponda     3     SEMIMEDIUM          2.50
# 4 NORTH GOA  ponda     4         MEDIUM          0.00
# 5 NORTH GOA  ponda     5          LARGE        182.64
# 6 NORTH GOA  ponda     6 ALL SIZE CLASS         41.09

tail(result)
# district tehsil si_no   holding_size inst_holdings
# 1 SOUTH GOA quepem     1       MARGINAL          0.30
# 2 SOUTH GOA quepem     2          SMALL          0.00
# 3 SOUTH GOA quepem     3     SEMIMEDIUM          0.00
# 4 SOUTH GOA quepem     4         MEDIUM          0.00
# 5 SOUTH GOA quepem     5          LARGE         23.50
# 6 SOUTH GOA quepem     6 ALL SIZE CLASS         15.77
```

RSelenium even supports headless browsing leveraging PhantomJS as described in this [vignette](http://rpubs.com/johndharrison/RSelenium-headless).

Comment: Thank Alex, this looks really promising. However, in the line remDrv$open() my R returns an error: Error : Summary: UnknownError Detail: An unknown server-side error occured while processing the command. Class: org.openqa.selenium.webDriverException                              
Could this have to do with my firewall settings?

Comment: In this case I would check out the [issue section](https://github.com/ropensci/RSelenium)  in RSelenium's GitHub repo. Should you struggle to find your answer there, just open a new issue.

Comment: I ran it on a different computer and it worked perfectly now. My best guess is that it did have something to with the firewall or anti virus settings.
Thanks a lot Alex!