# How to automate multiple requests to a web search form using R (Java function calls / triger)

Tags: r, web-scraping

I need to access the data in this [page](http://www.framinghamheartstudy.org/risk/gencardio.html), the "Using lipids" link at the bottom of it.

I already have seen:

[How to automate multiple requests to a web search form using R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5396461/how-to-automate-multiple-requests-to-a-web-search-form-using-r)

and:

[What if I want to web scrape with R for a page with parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16601520/what-if-i-want-to-web-scrape-with-r-for-a-page-with-parameters/16860430#16860430)

However the page I am trying to get the data from does not use forms submition rather than Java function calls. Do you know any posible solution?

Comment: Using lipids link brings up a javascript calculator. You can just inspect the javascript function it calls to recreate the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The information to recreate the calculator is given on the webpage. For example to
calculate the CVD 10 year risk for a male:

```
cvdRiskmale <- function(age, SBP, treated, smoke, dia, HDL, TC){
    eSum <- (log(age)*3.06117 +treated*1.99881*log(SBP) +(1-treated)*1.93303*log(SBP))
    eSum <- eSum + (smoke*0.65451 +dia*0.57367 -0.93263*log(HDL) + 1.12370*log(TC) )
    1-0.88936^exp(eSum - 23.9802)
}

>  cvdRiskmale(35, 125, 0,0, 0, 45, 180)
[1] 0.02638287

>  cvdRiskmale(50, 115, 0,1, 1, 45, 180)
[1] 0.2067156
```

compare with calculator with same options.

A similar function can be defined for females given the regression coefficients listed on the website.

Comment: Thank you very much! 
In this case it will work, however I would love to know how to extract from the java calls.

Comment: This is not Java its javascript.

Comment: You could use selenium webdriver or something similar to automate the browser.