# Automate multiple requests to a web search form using R

Tags: r, curl, web-scraping

I am trying to create a dataframe of combinations of place of residence and tax using https://swisstaxcalculator.estv.admin.ch/#/calculator/income-wealth-tax

I have seen [How to automate multiple requests to a web search form using R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5396461/how-to-automate-multiple-requests-to-a-web-search-form-using-r) and [Scrape tables by passing multiple search requests using R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43528714/scrape-tables-by-passing-multiple-search-requests-using-r) but both those cases work by building new URLs and I don't think this works for admin.ch (the URL always stays the same).

Using the browser inspector I can extract query from a random calculation and it looks like this:

```
curl 'https://swisstaxcalculator.estv.admin.ch/delegate/ost-integration/v1/lg-proxy/operation/c3b67379_ESTV/API_calculateSimpleTaxes' \
  -H 'Connection: keep-alive' \
  -H 'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*' \
  -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.75 Safari/537.36' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8' \
  -H 'Origin: https://swisstaxcalculator.estv.admin.ch' \
  -H 'Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin' \
  -H 'Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors' \
  -H 'Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty' \
  -H 'Referer: https://swisstaxcalculator.estv.admin.ch/' \
  -H 'Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8,fr;q=0.7' \
  -H 'Cookie: SCDID_S=ji-7X06i9sLI29sYA_JLmUSOd6JpMHsgFG_8ilp1l6EZz8h7y2PMjA$$' \
  --data-binary '{"SimKey":null,"TaxYear":2019,"TaxLocationID":100000000,"Relationship":1,"Confession1":5,"Children":[],"Confession2":0,"TaxableIncomeCanton":30000,"TaxableIncomeFed":30000,"TaxableFortune":0}' \
  --compressed
```

It's quite clear I should change the part after `--data-binary` so I create a vector of taxable incomes and then a vector of `--data-binary`:

```
taxable_inc <- seq(30000, 150000, by = 1000)

data <- paste0('{"SimKey":null,"TaxYear":2019,"TaxLocationID":100000000,"Relationship":1,"Confession1":5,"Children":[],"Confession2":0,"TaxableIncomeCanton":',
               taxable_inc,
               ',"TaxableIncomeFed":',
               taxable_inc,
               ',"TaxableFortune":0}')
```

The next part would be to pass/execute this query and capture the answer but I do not know how to to this. Since the query starts with curl I looked at packages curl and RCurl but I really do not understand the link between handles, urls and queries....

Comment: what is the question ?

Comment: @BertrandMartel I clarified the question. Thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [httr](https://httr.r-lib.org/) to make the call and specify `encode = "json"` to automatically set the header `Content-Type: application/json` like in [curl](/questions/tagged/curl) and encode the `body` parameter as a JSON object :

```
library(httr)

url <- 'https://swisstaxcalculator.estv.admin.ch/delegate/ost-integration/v1/lg-proxy/operation/c3b67379_ESTV/API_calculateSimpleTaxes'

r <- POST(url, body = list(
    SimKey = NULL,
    TaxYear = 2019,
    TaxLocationID = 100000000,
    Relationship = 1,
    Confession1 = 5,
    Children = array(),
    Confession2 = 0,
    TaxableIncomeCanton = 30000,
    TaxableIncomeFed = 30000,
    TaxableFortune = 0
), encode = "json", verbose())

data = content(r, "parsed")
print(str(data))
```

which gives :

```
{"response":{"IncomeSimpleTaxCanton":1747,"FortuneTaxCanton":0,"IncomeSimpleTaxCity":1747,"IncomeTaxChurch":0,"IncomeTaxCity":1380,"IncomeSimpleTaxFed":119,"PersonalTax":0,"FortuneTaxCity":0,"FortuneSimpleTaxCanton":0,"IncomeTaxFed":119,"FortuneSimpleTaxCity":0,"IncomeTaxCanton":2699,"Location":{"TaxLocationID":100000000,"ZipCode":"1000","BfsID":5586,"CantonID":23,"BfsName":"Lausanne","City":"Lausanne","Canton":"VD"},"FortuneTaxChurch":0}}
```